# All new items have same ID# 0

Tags: control-panel, database, upgrade

I just updated a site from 2.6 to 2.9.2.

It's been very buggy since and nothing seems to work. I think I found the problem but I don't know where to fix.

All new entries have the same ID of 0 regardless if an entry, asset, asset folder, user etc.

New Assets load but don't stick to an already created entry(when I add an asset and save the entry and then go back, it is not there). Thumbnails of new Assets are wrong. Duplicate empty Assets folders are created in the CP when I update indexes.

Freeform does not submit because the url passed when submitting the form is .../?ACT=0. I get a blank page.

If I add user, I can log in fine but if I add a newer user, the password is now wrong, again because now both users have the ID of 0.

Anyone know why the ID column is defaulting to 0?

Comment: Made a little headway. I see in my database that none of the columns for ID's are set to primary key nor AUTO_INCREMENT. Any idea how this could have happened or how to fix?

Answer (score 1):

Turned out to be a boinked database migration or something went wrong with the upgrade wizard. Never could figure it out. I ended up having to go to the original files and start the process again. Second upgrade went without issue.

Always backup.